# Atomicity vs Memory model vs Out of order execution

Tags: multithreading, atomic, memory-model

I know an `atomic operation` means an operation that appears to be instantaneous from the perspective of all other threads. So when a value is updated, all threads see the same change.

In the world of `memory models` (weak, strong and sequentially consistent) it appears to be also dealing with the order of instruction execution. So one instruction might run before it's previous instruction.

We also have the concept of `out of order execution`. When a CPU pipeline is idle, it can fetch an instruction out of order, execute it and store the result until its actually the time of executing that instruction.

These concepts all sound the same to me, are the pretty much referring to the same thing?

Comment: They are three separate points of view on instructions and memory, each bringing something unique to the table. See "https://wiki.osdev.org/Atomic_operation" "https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/" "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining"

Comment: Re, "...So when a value is updated, all threads see the same change."  That is not what "atomic" means.  It means that other threads will either see the operation completely done or not done at all. No thread will see it half-way done. In most programming languages that have "atomic" types or an `atomic` keyword, there is an additional, vague promise that the change will _quickly_ become visible to other threads. But if thread A updates an atomic variable while thread B examines it "at the same time," _nothing_ can predict which thread will win that race.

Comment: "Car," "road," "itinerary," pretty much the same thing? Well, no. But they're deeply inter-related.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Because of out of order execution of memory operations, "at the same time" is not even clearly defined.

Comment: "_can fetch an instruction out of order_" You can't do that. I wonder what that would ever look like. You can only decode the next instruction, and the one after it, etc. You can't even begin decoding any binary code out of order w/ variable size encoding of Intel as you wouldn't know the beginning of an instr. Out of order refer to running computations not parse asm.

Comment: @curiousguy, I was lazy. Hence, the scare quotes. But if what we're talking about is the order of operations on the main memory, if the memory is not dual-ported, and if you want to go full-pedantic mode, then it is outright _impossible_ for any two operations to happen at the same time. The memory system will serialize them.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes from the point of view of the memory system. But it doesn't have to agree with the instr apparent exec order in any thread. (I assume by "main memory" you mean the whole system not the physical RAM.)

Answer (score 0):

The following is a very simplistic and informal description and not at a good technical level. It's only meant to give some general intuition of the process.

> So one instruction might run before it's previous instruction.

That may be true or false depending on what you mean. But programs are never run as if the order of their assembly instructions had been randomly shuffled, obviously.

The out of order execution refers to the fact that sometimes the later instructions in program order don't need the result of earlier computer to be started, and can be started early compared to sequential order.

The out of order execution might fetch data in memory in advance and see it as it was in the past when the sequential execution time finally arrives. The CPU may (or may not) monitor these changes in memory of values read in advance and throw away result of these computations done in advance.

The CPU can always read memory in advance, speculatively (not knowing for sure such access will really be performed) that is without due cause as the CPU can hide any memory fault resulting from such access, so if the program takes a path of execution that does not perform these reads, their result is dropped including any memory access violation.

A compiler cannot in general perform these transformations that had memory accesses that programs may do or not do in the future because:

1. they may cause memory access violations that would interrupt the program with a signal
2. at the time the value is needed, it may be been modified

(Regarding the 2. the language may allow the compiler to know which memory reference alias with which other one, limiting which objects may be modified by a write.)

CPU may not perform a memory modification in advance until the execution of that write is certain in program execution.